# Should we allow questions about programming languages?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

While they aren't "languages" in the traditional sense, programming languages certainly differ from one another. In some cases, learning programming languages can be like learning spoken languages, and we could offer some techniques to learn programming languages faster.

I'm not talking about what is allowed on StackOverflow. I'm asking about questions to quickly gain mastery over programming languages, like "Should I learn multiple programming languages at once?" or "Should I learn binary/octal before learning X language?" Questions about specific programming languages and problems wouldn't belong here, just as questions about specific spoken languages and grammar don't.

Comment: I'd wager that on one of the several existing Stack Exchange sites related to programming, at least one would be suited for this kind of question.  However, I'd be careful and ask about this topic on the site's meta first.  Also note that general judgment questions (e.g. questions with "should" in the title) are likely to be rejected on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Interesting how this question has 10 upvotes while this one, http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/150/are-questions-about-animal-communication-on-topic?rq=1, asking about a similar topic has 9 downvotes.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## No, not at all!

We are a natural language site. Programmers/Stack Overflow can cover most programming aspects.

Every site has their stream off-topic questions, adding programming to our scope will introduce a whole another stream of off-topic questions

Answer (score -2):

I would say no.

I don't know how useful or useless a site for learning programming languages is, but I think there's not much overlap between learning a programming language and learning a natural language, which isn't just questions about learning in general (eg "What is Anki?").